# Preventing user from moving between rendered tabs during post call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a page with various tabs. Under one tab is a functionality to upload a json file. This upload is done using a form tag.

tab4.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_tag({action: :add}, multipart: true, id: 'myform') do %>
        <%= file_field_tag 'json_file' %>
    <% end %>
    <button id="upload-button">UPLOAD</button>
```

On submit of the form tag, I call a function in the controller via the routes.rb resources and jquery.

Routes.rb:

```
resources :controller do
    collection do
      post 'add'
    end
  end
```

Jquery submit form:

```
$('#upload-button').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#json_file').val()) {
            $('#myform').submit();
        }
    });
```

controller.rb:

```
def add
    file = params[:json_file]
    file_content = file.read
    json_content = JSON.parse(file_content, symbolize_names: true)
    begin
      // post call
      redirect_to :some_other_page
    rescue 
      // post call fails with exception
      redirect_to // same page with a param to show failure
    end
  end
```

This function sends the content of json file in a post body to another service.

When this post call is happening, I want to prevent the user from switching between the other tabs available to him in the ruby on rails app? Is there a way to achieve this?

I thought of using an ajax call on the form submit, show an overlay with a spinner, then call the `add` function in the controller and until completion prevent the user from clicking anywhere.

Is there a better solution to achieve this?

Comment: Is the page reloaded after the post call happens?

Comment: Yes it is. In case of successful post, it redirects to another tab. In case of failure, it displays a error message on the same tab

Comment: You can prevent the user from clicking in your `$('#upload-button').on('click', function () {...}` callback. When the page reloads, the restriction will disappear by itself.

Comment: thanks. I have added the final solution as an answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using @chumakoff suggestion. I gave each of the tabs a class and on submit prevented clinking on them. After reload the behavior goes back to default.

```
$('#upload-button').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#json_file').val()) {
        preventNavigation();  
        $('#myform').submit();
    }
});

function preventNavigation() {
        $(".tab").on('click', function(){
            alert("Please wait till the upload is complete");
            return false;
        });
}
```

This results in the user getting an alert message when he clicks on the tabs during the post call thus preventing him from navigating away.